# jQuery event.keyCode NOT detecting alphanumerics

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, jquery-events

I have written a script to detect what key the user has clicked and act based on the key (if its alphanumeric) but it is not working so far and has no errors.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#my_field").keydown(function(event) { 
        var additional = new Array(8,9,13,27,35,36,37,38,39,46); 
        var numbers = new Array(48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,144); 
        var letters = new Array(65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90); 
        var AllowedKeyCode = 
            (jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, additional) >= 0) 
                || 
            (jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, letters) >= 0) 
                || 
            ((!event.shiftKey) && (jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, numbers) >= 0)) 
                || 
            ((event.ctrlKey) && (event.keyCode == 65 || event.keyCode == 67 || event.keyCode == 86)); 
        if (AllowedKeyCode === false) {event.preventDefault();} 
    }); 
});
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal syntax for an array in Javascript is:

```
var additional = [8,9,13,27,35,36,37,38,39,46];
```

As opposed to:

```
var additional = new Array(8,9,13,27,35,36,37,38,39,46);
```

The issue might be that you have no return action. It is quite tricky to see in what you have posted.

Try changing:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to

```
return false;
```